# Is this true: $\frac{f(x)}{1-c-o(1)}= \frac{f(x)}{1-c}(1-o(1))$

Tags: limits, notation, asymptotics

Let $f$ be a function, for example $f(x)=log(1+x)$ and let $c$ be some constant $>0$ (for simplicity, we may assume that it is different from 1).

Is this true:

$$\frac{f(x)}{1-c-o(1)}= \frac{f(x)}{1-c}(1-o(1))?$$

What is the difference between $-o(1)$ and $+o(1)$, when both contain positive and negative functions?

Comment: You can eliminate $f(x)$ from condition and change $1-c$ to... $c$, for example

Comment: So you mean my problem reduces to asking whether $\frac{1}{c-o(1)}=\frac{1-o(1)}{c}$? And we have $\frac{1}{c-o(1)}=\frac{1}{c}+\frac{o(1)}{c^2 - c o(1)}=\frac{1}{c}(1 + \frac{o(1)}{c-o(1)})= \frac{1}{c}(1+o(1))$?

Comment: There is no difference between $-o(1)$ and $o(1)$: both are functions tends to $0$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this helped a lot.

Comment: Oh, and by the way: For functions not (necessarily) tending to 0? Say $o(x^2)$ for $x \rightarrow \infty$, is then $+o(x^2)$ the same as $-o(x^2)$?

Comment: see definition of $o$-small: $o(f(x))$ is function with property $o(f(x)) / f(x) \to 0$ when $x\to x_0$. $+0$, $-0$ and $const\cdot 0$ are the same things.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Do you know then why so many people differentiate in notation between $-o(1)$ and $+o(1)$ then? This seems to be confusing to me.

Comment: I don't know. May be it's strange to write smth like $-o(1)=o(1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may observe that, as $u \to 0$, you have
$$
\frac1{1-u}=1+u+O(u^2)
$$ implying
$$
\frac1{1-u}=1+O(u) \tag1
$$  as $u \to 0$.

Here, using $(1)$, you may write, for $c \neq 1$,
$$
\frac{f(x)}{1-c-o(1)}=\frac{f(x)}{1-c}\left(\frac1{1- o(1)}\right)=\frac{f(x)}{1-c}\left(1+ o(1)\right)
$$ since clearly $\dfrac{o(1)}{1-c}=o(1)$ and $O(o(1))=o(1)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think this helped a lot. Can you help me in differentiating $+o(1)$ and $-o(1)$?

Comment: @user136457 You are welcome! Observe that $+o(1)$ and $-o(1)$ are the same.